# Minimize response time from Google AdWords Script

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

In Google Script it is [recommended](http://googleappsscript.blogspot.se/2010/06/optimizing-spreadsheet-operations.html) to store operations in an array, then calling the methods once all the operations has been constructed, to minimize response time every time a service is called.

For example in AdWords:

### Script A

```
var adGroupBuilder = campaign.newAdGroupBuilder(); 

for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  var adGroupOperation = adGroupBuilder
    .withName(i.toString())
    .build();
}

var adGroups = adGroupOperation.getResult(); // method call
```

Executes in **less than a second**.

### Script B

```
var adGroupBuilder = campaign.newAdGroupBuilder(); 

for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  var adGroupOperation = adGroupBuilder
    .withName(i.toString())
    .build();

  var adGroups = adGroupOperation.getResult(); // method call
}
```

Executes in **almost 6 minutes**.

In AdWords, an `AdGroup` can have several `Ads`, and in order to create an `Ad` there must be a corresponding `AdGroup`.

I have an external API which returns about 15 000 entities in batches of 1000 each, for which I am developing a Google Script that convert these into `AdGroups` with corresponding `Ads`. Obviously, to make that many individual calls to their services results in a timeout error. So I would like to break those down into 15 calls, with an array of 1000 entities each.

---

Now, I would like to know if there is possible to add `Ads` into the array of operations that is called by the method `getResults()`, or if the `AdGroup` object needs to be instantiated before I can create an `Ad` for it?

Because if not I see no other option than to make an individual call to the AdWords services for every entity that I want to turn into an `Ad`, but then the response time would be very high, and a different structure is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by pushing the operations into an array then iterating through it as suggested [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/concepts/builders).

### Script C

```
var adGroupBuilder = campaign.newAdGroupBuilder(); 
var operations = [];

for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  var adGroupOperation = adGroupBuilder
    .withName(i.toString())
    .build();
  operations.push(adGroupOperation);
}

for (var i = 0; i < operations.length; i++) {
  var adGroup = operations[i].getResult();
  var adOperation = adGroup.newTextAdBuilder()
    .withHeadline("headline of ad")
    .withDescription1("first line of ad description")
    .withDescription2("second line of ad description")
    .withDisplayUrl("www.example.com")
    .withDestinationUrl("http://www.example.com")
    .build();
}

var ad = adOperation.getResult();
```

Which executes in **around 8 seconds**.

---

However, I am still not so sure as of why that would be faster as there are still 1000 individual calls to their services with this badboy: `operations[i].getResult()`. I would assume it has something to do with how Google handles the calls on their end, perhaps through catching?

If anyone could share some light on this it would be appreciated!